# In postman-test section, can we read excel and fetch the data for validation purpose?

Tags: javascript, rest, automation, postman, postman-testcase

[image]
In **postman-Tests** section, I want to read excel and fetch the data into one variable. Then use that data for response validation purpose.

can anyone suggest a possible way to do that?

Comment: You can do that with collection runner, use variables and get the different value from excel to test.

Comment: @Div i think collection runner is to create api request right? isn't it? if yes how we'll take bunch of expected data from excel and store in a variable? could you give small example?

Comment: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/